# How to parse all data from 1 table to another page?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I have printed the table get from database like below
[image]
And my code

```
print "<form id='form1' name='form1' method='post' action='http://localhost/live/index.php?m=sync&a=update'>";
while($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    print "<table border=1 width=100%>";
    print "<tr><td width=5%><input name='taskid' type='text' value=".$db_field['task_id']." readonly=readonly></td>";
    /*print "<td width=10%>".$db_field['task_name']."</td>";*/
    print "<td width=5%><input name='percent' type='text' value=".$db_field['task_percent_complete']." readonly=readonly></td>";
    print "</table>";
}
print "<input name='Sync' type='submit' value='Sync' id='Sync' />";
print "</form>";
mysql_close($db_handle); /*.$db_handle */ /*<---to check the resource link and id*/
}
else{
    print"Failed" ;//.$db_handle;
```

So what i want to know how to parsing all the datas from the database to another page like the action i want to send, because now i just can parsing 1 data in 1 table when i click the sync button like below is my parsing code in another page
The image below is the parsing code
[image]

I have no idea how to display all the data in new page...it is need to use loop? im newbie, big thanks

Comment: oh....boy, man, ask shorter and more focused questions. We want to help, just can't. This site is targeted for small focused questions. Not big design/complete module programming.

Comment: mine also just short question, i just want to know how to parse all data from 1 table to another page, thats all, sorry that i didn't clarify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit based on comments below:

For starters, in the first code, move the `print "<table border=1 width=100%>";` and `print "</table>";` parts outside the `while` loop because the table is getting generated twice as two separate tables.

What's happening with the current code is that the second pair of fields `taskid` and `percent` are overwriting the first because the names are the same, so you only see the [second pair of values](http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/378/capturesta.png) in your screenshot. You need to **make the input field names an array: put square brackets `[]` in the name** so that `taskid` and `percent` are automatically arrays in `$_POST`. This is what the HTML source should look like in the form:

```
<input name='taskid[]' type='text' ...>
<input name='percent[]' type='text' ...>
```

*(Or manually subscript them like `taskid_0`, `percent_0` and `taskid_1`, `percent_1`; but then you have to decide when to stop looping or use variable variables.)*

After that, in the target page where you are processing `$_POST["taskid"]`, it will be an array which you can access as `$_POST["taskid"][0]`, `$_POST["percent"][0]` and `$_POST["taskid"][1]`, `$_POST["percent"][1]`. So loop through that when updating the database and generating your 2nd html:

```
print_r($_POST["taskid"]);  // verify that this is an array
print_r($_POST["percent"]); // also an array
$i=0;
foreach ($_POST["taskid"] as $t) {
    // not using $t, that's just for looping convenience
    // do sql insert/update here, i'm just showing how you'd loop the array
    print "<td><input type='text' name='".$_POST["taskid"][$i]."' readonly=readonly></td>";
    print "<td><input type='text' name='".$_POST["percent"][$i]."' readonly=readonly></td>";
    $i++;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Some pointers: 1. Don't put images of your code, just paste the code. 2. The generated HTML copy-pasted (browser -> view source) is more useful than an image of the page.

---

*version 1:*
**1.** If I understand it correctly, you want to **show the form on one page** and when the user clicks `Sync` (`sumbit`) you want it to **go to another page which will process the form**?

Use the [`target` attribute of the `<form>` element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp) (link). Like:

```
<form action="form_action.php" method="post">
```

Or,
**2.** If you want to **process the form first (same page) and send the user to another page**:

- send an [HTTP 302 re-direct + Location header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx).
- You can also [set the redirect in your HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Refresh_Meta_tag_and_HTTP_refresh_header)  after processing the page using:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/" />
  ```

Comment: actually i can get all the data and print out in one page, but then i want to parse those data from current page to another page, but i dunno how to parse all the data as i just can parse the one data to another page, the coding is at the second image

Comment: Do you want to parse the `form` data twice? Or do you want a reference to the records you created? Or so you want to reference only that result table? Maybe clarify your question first.

Comment: If you want the user's input values to be saved, then use cookies. If you want to read the table's records from only **that** form post then generate a transaction id (random number) and store it in the database or in a separate table temporarily. Then include that random number in the URL (or cookie) so that when the user opens the related page, you can match the transaction id with the data.

Comment: ok, then i wanna ask like the 1st image you see, it has 2 data right, then when i click the sync, it will redirect me to another page (actually is second website cause you can see the action that i put for sync button), which the code is the 2nd image, i just can get 1 data, so do you know what the problem of the code at the 2nd image? thanks for answering my question again

Comment: Ok, that's a clearer way to put it. What is the query you are running in the line `while($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))`? Can you paste the output of `print_r($db_field);` if you add it inside the while() loop. And what is the HTML output of the code in the 2nd image?

Comment: here the query 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
And the output is the 1st image, and the output of 2nd image is here http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/378/capturesta.png

Comment: This the output of print_r($db_field)`Array ( [task_id] => 1  [task_percent_complete] => 95)Array ( [task_id] => 2  [task_percent_complete] => 75)`

Comment: Edited answer based on this extended discussion. Posted above.

Comment: hey @aneroid thanks man!! it finally can parse all the data!! big thanks! so if i want update and save to new page database, i just code inside the `for each`?? which value i need to get? sorry that i ask too many question..haha

Comment: Yes, use `foreach` with array variables (`[]` notation). Which value? Whichever is entered in the form. Some will have arrays, others not, so process the non-array values like "name" outside the foreach loop. Btw, if you're happy with the answer, **["accept"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/193893) and [vote up](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up)**

Comment: oh ya, i forget to vote..XD,so thats mean i can name any name the input type right? can it be i put a button there, when they want to update then click that, then all the coding of update is on other php page? because i not really sure it can update automatically in `foreach`?

Comment: `input type` should be standard HTML input types. The `name` field can be anything but avoid space obviously. Don't put the array `[]` part at the end of the form field name if it's not supposed to be multiple. If you put many submit buttons, remember that without AJAX, the entire form will be submitted/page will get reloaded as per the form 'action'. (You don't have enough rep to move this chat). For further unrelated questions, use google ;-) or post a new question.

Comment: ya that is sad case cause i only need 1 rep then can move to chat..haha..anyway thanks to you to take your time for helping me =)